# enable or disable textbox inside td when checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My Edit.cshtml -

```
<table id="scDetails" class="dataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>RItem</th>
                <th>IChecked</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           @foreach (var fback in Model.Fbacks)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => fback.FItem)

                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => fback.RItem)
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => fback.IChecked)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => fback.Notes)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

When Checkbox "IChecked" on table row is checked, the textbox "Notes" should be enabled otherwise disabled.

Comment: I tried using this.  $("input[type=checkbox][id*=IsChecked]").click(function () {

          if (this.checked)  

            $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type=text][id*=Notes]").attr("disabled", false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#scDetails tbody input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        var notes = $(this).closest('tr .notes');
        notes.prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

Just give your textbox the `notes` classname so that the previous selector works properly:

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => fback.Notes, new { @class = "notes" })</td>
```

Remark: the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function used in my example is the recommended approach to set properties such as disabled or readonly on a textbox. It is available starting from jQuery 1.6. If you are using an older version of jQuery you could use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--    
function fnDisabled(trecval)
    {
        if(trecval=="2")
        {
            document.getElementById('inputname').disabled=true;
        }
    }
</script>
```